# Rendering w/ JS element in a li

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I'm working to include in my rails application some prototype to display pages associated with a site. Without JS it works properly, but when I tell the page to update through a RJS with something like - 
`page.insert_html :bottom, 'page_listing', :partial => 'page'`

I have a partial page -

`<li><%= page.url %> - <em><%= page.status %></em></li>`

in my show view I also have -

`<ul id="page_listing">`
 `<% @site.pages.each do |page| %>`
  `<%= render :partial => 'page', :locals => {:page => page} %>`
  `<% end %>`
`</ul>`

So with just ERB its fine, but with rjs, I get -

`ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy to String (ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy#to_str gives ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy)):`

So basically I think its not able to place into the li the paramaters. (If I refresh the page it does show the correct text) 
But I'm not sure where to go to find this answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. 
It looks like in my partial I have to include the whole loop. 
`<% @site.pages.each do |page| %>`
`<li> .....</li>`
`<% end %>`

I guess live and learn